# Closing A Winform That Was Dynamically Created

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am dynamically creating a winform and have the winform declared as a class variable.  I have the form launching, and displaying exactly as I need, however my `Close()` event does not close the form as I need.

How should this syntax be modified so that the dynamically created sub-form closes on button press?

(See compile errors commented in code below)

```
//class variable
private Form noempselected; 

private void btnValidateData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string employee = cboEmployeeSelect.Text;
    if (employee == "--Select An Employee--")
    {
        using (noempselected = new Form())
        {
            Label messagelabel = new Label();
            messagelabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(378, 22);
            messagelabel.Name = "lblMessageToUser";
            messagelabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 9);
            messagelabel.Text = "Please select an Employee!";
            Button closebutton = new Button();
            closebutton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(126, 43);
            closebutton.Name = "btnCloseForm";
            closebutton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(101, 42);
            closebutton.TabIndex = 7;
            closebutton.Text = "Close";
            closebutton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            closebutton.Click += new System.EventHandler(CloseForm_Click);
            noempselected.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            noempselected.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(396, 160);
            noempselected.Controls.Add(messagelabel);
            noempselected.Controls.Add(closebutton);
            noempselected.Name = "noempselected";
            noempselected.Text = "No Employee Selected";
            noempselected.ResumeLayout(false);
            noempselected.PerformLayout();
            noempselected.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    private void CloseForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        //Simply using close does nothing
        //Close();

        //This throws compile error of The type or namespace name 'noempselected' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  
        noempselected nes = new noempselected();
        nes.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Why you have initialize with noempselected nes = new noempselected(); it is form

Comment: @programtreasures - I was trying to see if instantiating a new instance of the form would permit the close() event to fire properly

Comment: With absolutely everything hardcoded, why bother creating it in code?

Comment: @Plutonix - I do not follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When simply calling `Close()`, that actually applies to your top level form, not the one you want to close. It is equivalent to `this.Close()`, and is not what you're looking for. The reason it does nothing, is because your subform is modal, thus `this.Close()` is pretty well ignored. (As a test, try closing the main form manually when your subform is opened. Spoiler: Nothing will happen.)

Also, You can't use the sender here, because the sender is a button. Casting a `Button` to a `Form` will return `null`.

For your code to work as is, use this:

```
private void CloseForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    noempselected.Close();
}
```

Lastly, `noempselected` is a private field, not a type. For this reason, `noempselected nes = new noempselected();` is not at all something you can do. You had the right idea, just wrong syntax!